# How do I check if Netty Jax Rs server is ready

Tags: java, jax-rs, netty, resteasy

I am using the following to start a netty jax rs server:

```
    NettyJaxrsServer netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
    netty.setHostname(HOST);
    netty.setPort(port);        
    netty.setDeployment(resteasyDeployment);        

    // Some optional extra configuration
    netty.setKeepAlive(true);
    netty.setRootResourcePath("/");
    netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
    netty.setIoWorkerCount(16);
    netty.setExecutorThreadCount(16);

    LOGGER.info("Starting REST server on " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));        
    // Start the server
    //("Starting REST server on " + System.getenv("HOSTNAME")); 
    netty.start();  
    LOGGER.info("Started!");
```

This works fine but there is no way to check if the server is actually up and can accept REST requests. I have been using try/catch requests to the REST interface, and retrying if I get an exception, with a wait in the catch block. It works but it is a bit messy:

```
private void bringUpInterface(SlaveRestInterface slaveAgent, Target localTarget) {
    LOGGER.info("Bringing up interface on " + localTarget.getHostName());
    Response r = null;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean isReady = false;
    long wait = 50;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        while (!isReady) {
            try {
                r = slaveAgent.ping();
                r.close();
                isReady = true;
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                SYS_LOGGER.info(" [OK]" + " (" + (endTime - startTime + "ms") + ")");

            } catch (ProcessingException ce) {
                if(r != null) {
                    r.close();
                }

                if (count == DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SEC) {
                    throw new TimeoutException("Failed to start REST interface in " + DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SEC
                            + "second(s)");
                }
                Thread.sleep(wait);
                wait *= 2;
                count++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isReady = false;
                throw new FatalException("Couldn't connect to REST interface on " + localTarget.getHostName());
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException ie) {
        isReady = false;
        throw new FatalException("REST interface did not come up on "  + localTarget.getHostName());
    }
}
```

I am wondering if I can override the start() method, and add code to ping the endpoint maybe using a HttpRequest. There does not seem to be any programmatic way to see if the server is up.

Comment: For this to work, the server would need to have a two-stage setup where the first step is to open the server socket and the second one is to actually fetch new connections from it. Very few java servers features this kind of setup, so you end up having to poll a socket to figure it out. It's kind of sad actually.

Answer (score 1):

If you can hook into Netty, take your `ServerBootstrap` and do the following:

```
ChannelFuture bindFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(port);
//Wait for port to be bound
Channel channel = bindFuture.sync().channel();
//Bound here - start your tests        
//Wait for closure (optional)
channel.closeFuture().sync();
```